# Where is vtkSphere::ComputeBoundingSphere in in VTK's Python bindings

Tags: python, vtk, mayavi

I'm using Anaconda 64-bit on Windows with VTK version 5.10.1 and MayaVi version 4.3.1.  Is `vtkSphere::ComputeBoundingSphere` available from VTK's Python bindings?  I have a set of 3D points for which I want the minimum bounding sphere.  As far as I can see, `vtkSphere::ComputeBoundingSphere` does this in C++ but I can't find this function in the Python bindings for VTK.

I have found the class `vtk.vtkSphere` and the output of `help(vtk.vtkSphere)` mentions "Additional methods are available for sphere-related computations, such as computing bounding spheres for a set of points, or set of spheres.".  So, where is this function though?

Comment: I could not find it either. As you might know, the vtk bindings just link to the C++ docs.

Comment: I have found the CGAL Python bindings quite useful, at the expense of an extra dependency unfortunately.  See my answer below for links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't found evidence that VTK's Python bindings expose `vtkSphere::ComputeBoundingSphere`, but I have found the CGAL library which has Python bindings that do expose N-dimensional bounding sphere calculations.  The C++ function documentation is at http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Bounding_volumes/classCGAL_1_1Min__sphere__d.html.

I used the outdated bindings at http://cgal-python.gforge.inria.fr/ (because there is a Windows installer available at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cgal-python) but there are newer bindings available at https://code.google.com/p/cgal-bindings/ if anyone wants to give them a try.

Assuming you have a list of vertices called `verts`, the following code constructs a Min_sphere_3 object from which one can get the centre and radius of the bounding sphere.

```
import CGAL

min_sphere = CGAL.Geometric_Optimisation.Min_sphere_3()

for pt in verts:
    min_sphere.insert(CGAL.Point_3(pt[0], pt[1], pt[2]))

# Sphere properties: min_sphere.center(), min_sphere.squared_radius().
```